# Issue of browser srcolling on IE9 with Flash app embedded

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scroll, focus, internet-explorer-9

Does anyone know of a solution to preventing the browser scrolling in IE9 desktop mode when a Flash app requires arrow key input?

In previous versions of IE this was prevented by putting the Wmode to either ‘direct’ or leaving it off entirely. This would enable the app to gain focus rather than the browser window.

However, this is not happening in the preview of IE9. No matter what, the browser keeps focus and as a result the window moves if an arrow key is pressed. This is obviously horrendous for game playing.

And I know the solution should be to drop Flash and use HTML5 but there are still plenty of Flash based games out there. Any potential solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the problem of *flash not gaining keyboard focus on the load of the page.*

If that is the case try, javascript `focus()` event as specified [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/give-keyboard-focus-embedded-movie.html).

Comment: Thanks Loxxy. i'll give it a go and let you know. I would vote this anwser up but I don't have the rep yet :-(

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach does not work. 
Even when adding a name attribute to the object and putting the following line in the body tag onLoad=”window.document.movieID.focus()”. The focus remains on the browser window.
The IE9 and below approach would be to remove the Wmode but this seems to no logher work in IE10.
This could be a serious over-sight unless someone knows an answer.
ately